# Найти дату с наибольшим числом записей

Tags: mysql

Есть такая табличка

```
CREATE TABLE statistics (
                       id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
                       time TIMESTAMP);
```

В эту табличку через произвольное время записываются значения, где time время выполнения операции с id. 
Мне необходимо найти дату из поля time, когда количество таких ID было максимальным за все время. В поле time хоронится дата в формате yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Пробывал делать так

```
select  max(x.mycount) from (SELECT  statistics.time as t , COUNT(*) as mycount
FROM statistics )x ORDER BY x.t DESC limit 1 ;
```

но без успехов. Ошибка 1140

Comment: `select d, count(*) n from stats group by date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d') d order by n desc limit 10`

Comment: @Lexx918 а что есть что в этом запросе??

Comment: d - дата, n - число записей в эту дату

Comment: ток я date_format сунул в группировку, а надо было в select - `select date_format(..) d, ..`. но эт просто уже домой пора и спать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  CAST(s.`time` AS DATE),
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `statistics` s
GROUP BY
  CAST(s.`time` AS DATE)
ORDER BY
  COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

1. Выбираем записи с разбивкой по дням (`GROUP BY CAST(s.`time`AS DATE)`)
2. считаем количество записей в каждой группе
3. сортируем по убыванию количества (`ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`)
4. выводим первую запись (`LIMIT 1`)

Comment: а как можно вывести еще и количество записей ?

Comment: @Alex.B Добавив `COUNT(*)` в список полей